# How can I use an extension context variable in the browser context?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to pass `startDate` and `endDate` to my chrome extension script but it doesn't work for some reason. I checked out the chrome extension documentation but I couldn't find any solution except for using the args property in `chrome.scripting.executeScript`. Nevertheless, it serializes the arguments so I can't actually use them.

```js
const startDate = document.getElementById("start-date")?.value;
const endDate = document.getElementById("end-date");
const searchButton = document.getElementById("search-button");

searchButton.addEventListener("click", async (startDate, endDate) => {
  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    args: [startDate],
    function: scrapCalendar,
  });
});

function scrapCalendar(startDate) {
  let pageDateRange = document
    .querySelector(
      "#sectionBody > div.con_cuer > div.tabla1 > div:nth-child(2) > div.tabder"
    )
    ?.innerText.split(" ");
  /*
  let goLastPageButton = document.querySelector(
    "#sectionBody > div.con_cuer > div.flechas_horario > div.izq"
  );
  let goNextPageButton = document.querySelector(
    "#sectionBody > div.con_cuer > div.flechas_horario > div.der"
  );*/
  let pageStartDate = pageDateRange[1];
  let pageEndDate = pageDateRange[3];
  console.log(startDate);
  console.log(pageStartDate + " - " + pageEndDate);
}
```

Comment: Parameters of executeScript/messaging/storage are always serialized so you're on the right track. Why is that a problem? Your code doesn't show how you use startDate.

Comment: @wOxxOm I don't get the actual value when I try to `console.log` it in `scrapCalendar`, is there any way to deserialize it?

Comment: It is perfromed automatically so start by verifying in devtools of the sender that you're sending the correct value.

Comment: @wOxxOm Damn, u were right. I had to cautiously debug what I was sending. I was trying to pass the arguments through the addEventListener function parameters, but then I realized it was a click event, so it was nonsense. I fixed it pulling the values from the addEventListener function instead of pulling them from the global scope, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by pulling the dates from the `addEventListener` function rather than the global scope. I thought I was passing the values to the addEventListener function in `async (startDate, endDate)` but they were only the function parameters names.

Solution:

```js
const searchButton = document.getElementById("search-button");

searchButton.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  const startDate = document.querySelector("#start-date")?.value;
  const endDate = document.querySelector("#end-date")?.value;
  let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    args: [startDate, endDate],
    func: scrapCalendar,
  });
});

function scrapCalendar(startDate, endDate) {
  let pageDateRange = document
    .querySelector(
      "#sectionBody > div.con_cuer > div.tabla1 > div:nth-child(2) > div.tabder"
    )
    ?.innerText.split(" ");
  /*
  let goLastPageButton = document.querySelector(
    "#sectionBody > div.con_cuer > div.flechas_horario > div.izq"
  );
  let goNextPageButton = document.querySelector(
    "#sectionBody > div.con_cuer > div.flechas_horario > div.der"
  );*/
  let pageStartDate = pageDateRange[1];
  let pageEndDate = pageDateRange[3];
  console.log(startDate + " * " + endDate);
  console.log(pageStartDate + " - " + pageEndDate);
}
```